# NSNumberFormatter with 0.1 issue

Tags: ios, string, swift, nsnumberformatter

I have code:

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1;
let strTest = formatter.stringFromNumber(0.1)
```

But strTest is equal to ",1", but I want "0,1". What properties do I need to configure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show zero you need to set `formatter.usesSignificantDigits = true`

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution `formatter.minimumSignificantDigits = 1`